# Redshift: serializable isolation error (1023) despite LOCK

Tags: amazon-redshift, etl

I am running several batch ETL operations in parallel on my Redshift cluster.

My pipeline does the following:

Do a a bunch of stuff on temporary staging table. At the end, upsert into the final table (permanent and shared across process) by doing:

```
BEGIN;
LOCK table X;
DELETE FROM X USING stage_table...
INSERT INTO X ...
END;
```

Still, when I have several process in parallel, some fail with:

> ERROR:  1023
>   DETAIL:  Serializable isolation violation on table - 142443, transactions > forming the cycle are: 388224, 388226 (pid:32012)

(where 142443 is my table X)

When I run the process one-by-one everything works like a charm. I've used the lock with success on other processes (and verified that it worked as intended) so I'm puzzled here. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why do you use INSERT instead of COPY? It might be better to redesign your ETL to be more ELT and use COPY and internal Redshift queries, to get much faster ingestion speed than the traditional old ETL processes.

Comment: My ETL classification was actually a bit misleading. Those are derived calculations based on data already in Redshift. Would it still seem make sense to use COPY there?

Comment: Hey, any luck? I'm just doing the same steps and getting the same error..

Comment: Nope, still having the same issue. I've made lots of changes so that it's much less frequent but still no luck.

Comment: Actually, if that helps, I've realized that most of the time, the error is thrown on read. e.g. if you do a SELECT on a table that may be updated while the SELECT is happening, you should try locking the table before doing the SELECT.

Comment: Couple things I've learned since I posted this question:

- The Redshift default LOCK is `EXCLUSIVE` not `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE`
- A `TRUNCATE` statement will automatically terminate a transaction block (and ends your lock)

Comment: Have you ever found  the solution ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is expected. The transaction isolation level used by Redshift is SERIALIZABLE as clearly stated in the [AWS Doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_BEGIN.html)

> > Note: READ UNCOMMITTED, READ COMMITTED, and REPEATABLE READ have no
> >     operational impact and map to SERIALIZABLE in Amazon Redshift.

Concretely speaking this means that if you run SQL statements in parallel that are not SERIALIZABLE (can be run in any order with no result difference), you will get the isolation level error.

By the way, Redshift give you tools to figure out which queries are conflicting. Using the numbers you get in the above log message you can query as follows:

```
select query, trim(querytxt) as sqlquery from stl_query where xid = 388224;
```

388224 the transaction_id that form the cycle.